# What's the difference between Guardian Angel I, II, and III?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Over at Duke Slava's heroic abilities in *Might & Magic Heroes VI*, I couldn't help but notice that the first 3 versions of the `Guardian Angel` ability are identical. What's the difference between them?

Is it the number of times I can cast them? I couldn't tell because I haven't had a single battle in which the meter reached full charge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The varying ranks of Guardian Angel affect not how *powerful* the effect is, but *who* it can affect.

> Rank 1 = Core Creatures only -- Praetorians, Vestels, and Marksmen.
>
> Rank 2 = Core *or* **Elite** Creatures -- Imperial Griffons, Radiant Glory,
>   Sun Crusader
>
> Rank 3 - Core *or* **Elite** *or* ***Champion*** Creatures -- any Haven unit.